# Falta revisar traducciones de "results found containing"

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducida-falta-revisar

Recién me doy cuenta que la página de resultados muestra "results found containing" al buscar cosas como [-[google*]](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=-%5Bgoogle*%5D) y que Mariano hizo la traducción hace 2 horas aproximadamente si no de todas si de varias de las cadenas que incluyen dicha frase.

Enlace a transifex [results found containing](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/135269758?q=results%20found%20containing)

Comment: Parece que ya está funcionando: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t88nG.png